# Redux saga never runs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to configure `redux-saga` v1.1.3 in my application.

I did with the README [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/) my configuration below.

In my project:

```sh
npm i redux-saga@1.1.3 --save
```

I have created `rootSaga.js` as follow:

```js
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export default (customSagas) => function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    ...customSagas,
  ])
}
```

> I turned the `rootSaga.js` into a function, because the rootSaga is within the core of my application and I needed to be able to add more customSaga to my application.

This is my updated `configureStore.js`:

```
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose,
} from 'redux';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
+ import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import { augmentStore } from '@nfen/redux-reducer-injector';

import storage from './storage';
import combineAppReducers from '../reducers';
+ import rootSagas from '../sagas';

function setupCreateReducer(customReducers = {}, reducerConfig) {
  return function createReducer() {
    return combineAppReducers({
      ...customReducers,
    }, reducerConfig);
  };
}

export default function configureStore(customReducers, customSagas, initialState = {}, persistConfig = {}, reducerConfig = {}) {
  const runtimePersistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
    storage,
    ...persistConfig,
    whitelist: [
      'preferences',
      ...(persistConfig.whitelist || []),
    ],
  };

  let composeEnhancers = compose;
  const reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {};
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (__DEV__ && typeof window === 'object') { // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
    if (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) {
      composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({});
    }
    /* eslint-enable */
  }

+  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(reduxSagaMonitorOptions);
-  const middlewares = combineAppMiddlewares([], reducerConfig.history);
+  const middlewares = combineAppMiddlewares([sagaMiddleware], reducerConfig.history);


-  const middlewares = [routerMiddleware(reducerConfig.history)];
+  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(reducerConfig.history)];

  const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];

  const createReducer = setupCreateReducer(customReducers, reducerConfig);
  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(runtimePersistConfig, createReducer());
  const store = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers),
  );
  // Extensions
+  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
+  store.runSaga(rootSagas(customSagas));

  augmentStore(createReducer, store);
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  return { store, persistor };
}
```

> In there, I use `redux` and `redux-persist`, I also configure redux development tools. and have some core features such as `preferences` being preconfigured and persistent

This is my `customSagas.js`:

```
import sessionsSaga from './sessionsSaga';

export default [
  sessionsSaga,
];
```

This is my `sessionSaga.js`:

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function* logout() {
  console.log('hello world');
}

export default function* logoutSaga() {
  yield takeLatest('LOGOUT' , logout);
}
```

And this is how I call the saga in my JSX:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Button
          push={() => dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })}
        >
          Logout Saga
        </Button>
    );
}
```

I can see that the `LOGOUT` type is dispatched in my redux dev tools, but I can't see the hello world.

Where am I failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do `yield all([...])` in `rootSaga` you have to **call** the functions like `sessionSaga()`. in your code  you are just listing the generator functions. see [root saga docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RootSaga.html)

i think something like:

```js
import { all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export default (customSagas) => function* rootSaga() {
  yield all(customSagas.map(saga => call(saga)));
}
```

could work.

Comment: This is not what's in the documentation, impressive that it work.